# how to add a factor to a sequence?

Tags: arrays, r, matrix

I'm analysing a dataset with some data-mining tools.The response variable has ten levels and I'm trying to create a classifier.

Here comes the problem.When using nnet and bagging function,the result is not that good and the 5th level is even not in the prediction.

I want to use a confusion matrix to analyse the classifier.but as the 5th level is not shown in the prediction I can't get a well-formed matrix.So how can I get a well-formed matrix?i.e. I want a 10*10 matrix.

The confusion matrix:

```
library("mda")#This is where **confusion** comes from
> confusion(pre.bag$class,CLASS)#here confusion acts like table
         true
predicted   1   2  3  4   6   7  8  9  10  5
       1  338   9  6  0   5  12 10  1  15 46
       2    9 549  1 59  18   0  3  0   0  6
       3   18   1 44  0   0   0  2  0   0  4
       4    0   1  0 21   0   0  0  0   0  0
       6    2  13  0  1 299   2  9  0   0  0
       7    5   2  1  0  10 231  6  0   1  0
       8    0   0  0  0   0   5 76  0   0  0
       9    5   1  0  0   0   0  0 62   0  0
       10   7   3  1  0   0   2  1  6 181 16
attr(,"error")
[1] 0.1231743
attr(,"mismatch")
[1] 0.03386642
```

Comment: Are you asking how to insert a row of zeros where the "5" row should be in the confusion matrix, or are you asking how to improve your classifier so that it correctly predicts some elements as being in the 5th level?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity.I'm just asking how to insert a row of zeros where the "5" row should be in the confusion matrix.

Comment: Hard to say without a reproducible example, but you could try converting `pre.bag$class` to a factor and specify its levels as `1:10`.

Comment: Where is the function `confusion()` coming from? (i.e. it's not in `MASS` or in any of the base R packages).

Comment: @joran Is it convinient for you to explain it in detail?It'll be really helpful~:)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Sorry for the wrong information.It comes from `mda` pack.

Comment: Don't take this the wrong way, but no. If you put more effort into your question by making it reproducible (self contained code that I can copy+paste and run on my computer) then I'd be willing to put more effort into my answer.

Comment: @joran The situation can be reproduced by:`a=c(1,1,2,2,2);b=c(1,1,2,2,3);
confusion(a,b);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pred <- factor(pre.bag$class, levels=levels(CLASS) )
confusion(pre.bag$class, CLASS)
```

(Tested with an fda-object.)